# Why does using an action name that is the same as a configured SpringBean name result in a ClassCastException?

Tags: grails, classcastexception, autowired, grails-controller

To reproduce this problem use the following steps.

1. Create a new Grails application.
2. Create a new controller called FooController
3. Add an action "bar" to FooController
4. In src/groovy, create a new class called Bar
5. In resources.groovy configure a SpringBean called bar

   `bar(Bar) {bean ->
       bean.autowire = 'byName'
   }`
6. Start the application and navigate to http:localhost:8080/[appContext]/foo/bar
7. You should get a stacktrace similar to this:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: Bar cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Closure
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(DevModeSanityFilter.groovy:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)'`

Why is this occuring? Is it a bug in Grails or expected behaviour?

I would expect that there should not be name clashes between configured SpringBeans and action names.

Comment: What version of Grails, and if 2.x is your `bar` action a closure or a method?

Comment: Grails 1.3.7, I'll try to reproduce the problem on 2.x as well.

Comment: I tried this on Grails 2.0.3 and it works fine using both a method and a closure as the action. 

Perhaps the solution is obvious: Upgrade the version of Grails I'm using for the project. :-)

I would still like to know why this is happening on 1.3.7 though... Thanks for the comment.

Comment: On Grails 2 actions-as-methods is the preferred approach, and any actions declared as closures are massaged into methods at compile time by an AST transformation.  Spring is still replacing the value of the `bar` property of your controller with the autowired bean but when invoking the action via a web request it's the method version that gets run (which has its own copy of the original closure code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Groovy syntax like

```
class FooController {
  def bar = {
    // do something
  }
}
```

gives the `FooController` class two public methods

```
public Object getBar() {
  return bar;
}

public void setBar(Object newBar) {
  bar = newBar;
}
```

The existence of the `setBar` method makes Spring consider it as a property to be autowired, and it replaces the closure value with your bean.  Grails itself only requires the getter method, so if instead you say

```
class FooController {
  final bar = {
    // do something
  }
}
```

(i.e. declare `bar` to be `final`) then Groovy will synthesize only the getter and not the setter, and Spring will not see `bar` as a property it can autowire.

Comment: Excellent! I tested the solution and the action works correctly now.

I've run into this problem numerous times before and just changed the action name without ever getting to the bottom of the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The action in the controller is a closure, which is transformed into a inner class. Your bean has the same name, so I believe you come to name collision through this. Did you try to rename the bean or the action?

Comment: Renaming the action or the bean obviously removes the problem, but that's not the question here...